# How can we make a 4 by 4 grid using css

Tags: html, css, layout

What is the right approach to make a 4by4 grid(4 rows and 4 columns) using CSS

I have tried it using column-count but could get the complete look of a grid, borders do not stretch to the elements correctly.

Do we have any other approach. If so please help

Following is the code

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  column-count: 4;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid;
  column-rule: 1px solid;
}
.box {
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.box .contents {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">c-1
    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-2

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-3

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-4

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">c-5

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-6

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-7

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-8

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">c-9

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-10

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-11

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-12

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">c-13

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-14

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-15

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">c-16

    <p class="contents"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you not know if it's correct? *Do you get a 4x4 grid?* Put a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: your link isn't working for me, just paste your code into your question. Hit edit and then hit Ctrl + M and paste your code into the snippet box

Comment: Welcome to SO! `I am trying to make a 4 by 4 grid using css and html… Please let me know if i have done correctly` doesn't tell us what you're trying to accomplish. If you got the result you wanted, it worked. If not, it didn't. `can you please let me know what is right process to follow` isn't really [what SO is for](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking): If you didn't get the result you wanted, you might ask "I wrote this code, thought the result would be x, the result was y, what went wrong?"). In its current for this question might be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That wouldn't work, no. Look at flex-box or float-right for a grid-type arrangement of `div` elements. Flexbox is especially powerful, really just need 2-3 lines of CSS to accomplish this:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
#container { width: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; background: green; }

#container > div { width: 25%; height: 25vw; border: white 1px solid; }
```

**What's happening:**

*box-sizing* - depending on what browser you're on, the 1px border will add to the overall width and break the grid (example: 25% of 100px box is 25px, but if your box sizing is off, the border can cause the box to "bloat" to 27px. If each box is 27px, one of the boxes is knocked down to the next row bc there's no space left on the row above it).

By setting it to border-box, it means we're including the border when specifying the DOM's width.

*width and height:*
25% works for width but not height, so we specify the height with the [vw](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw) measurement. Be careful with this unit, it's not supported by current version -1 (thanks IE).

*flex-everything*
Neat way to approach modern CSS layout. There are a lot of [bells and whistles](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but generally speaking I think the rules I used above are pretty self-explanatory. I'm happy to provide any clarification in the comments.

https://jsfiddle.net/z_herring/cg71okst/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you explain when to use flex layout and why t my approach of using column-layout does not work (or is wrong to use).Your explanation helps in understanding

Comment: @Geeky - I don't use display-column much, but from what I understand, it's for rendering text flow in a multi-column layout, similar to how you'd see a newspaper.  (https://jsfiddle.net/z_herring/ub5rvpyp/) See how the same paragraph stretches over multiple columns in the same div? column layout is primarily for controlling text flow without having to include multiple divs and slicing a single paragraph up.

Comment: **Flexbox** on the other hand, is about how DOM elements (like `divs`, `articles,` etc) are displayed on the page. If you need to arrange elements, use flexbox. If you need to flow text across a single div-element, use display-column.

Comment: Excellent primer on flexbox can be found here -> http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: Thanks @Zach Herring for the detailed explanation :)